# query statement containing variable won't execute

Tags: query

Very confused why the following code does not work.

```
function discount_State() {
if(is_page('cart')){
global $wpdb;

 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 $need = $current_user->ID;

$getID = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value from table where user_id = $need AND meta_key = 'shipping_state'"));

echo $getID;

  }
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'discount_State');
```

The problem is that when I put the user_id as a variable in the sql statement, the code is not executed. If I input a number for the user_id, the code works. I have tried using gettype to confirm that the $need is a integer. I have assigned $need to a number, ie $need = 12, and the code executes.

I can't figure out why the statement won't execute correctly the way it is written.

I have tried writing the variable as '$need' and "'.$need.'" with no success.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You're not using `prepare` correctly, refer to [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) for an example.

```
$wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
        SELECT meta_value FROM table
        WHERE user_id = %d
        AND meta_key = 'shipping_state'
        ",
        $need
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test your code but this is how I used inline PHP variables to work on some of my SQL in the past.
**From my notes:**

```
.$longitude.
```

So maybe

```
"SELECT meta_value from table where user_id = .$need. AND meta_key = 'shipping_state'"
```

I have also substituted successfully like this:

```
ASC LIMIT {$radius}
```

And

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM services WHERE service_name='$variable' ";
```

Comment: thanks for the response. unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: Have you printed $need to make sure its working correctly?

Comment: yeah, I echoed $need and the correct value returns.

Comment: PLEASE DIS-REGARD THIS QUESTION.
The code I initially inputted is correct. The problem was that I wasn't testing the code on a logged in user account. Obviously, the code will not execute correctly if a user isn't logged in because there is no shipping state to pull. Sorry! I knew it would be something I overlooked.